Bluetooth mouse stuck in disconnection loop
In order to fix another Bluetooth-related issue (file transfer not working), I had to reinstall bluez and blueman on my Debian 13 desktop.
However, since then, my Bluetooth mouse experience issues.
Issue 1 : Bluetooth not available
Sometimes, it's just the following error :
bluetoothd[3383]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03).
Bluetooth is just down, nothing can be done.
Non-optimal solutions :

Sometimes (i.e. I don't know the cause) rfkill list shows Bluetooth as soft blocked so rfkill unblock bluetooth solves the problem. It happens even if I already unblocked it in the past.

Otherwise, rfkill list shows Bluetooth is not blocked. However the same Failed to add UUID error happens. An arbitrary number of systemctl restart bluetooth eventually makes it back to normal.


Issue 2 : Disconnection loop
When issue 1 is solved, or does not happen, I can successfully use Bluetooth, for instance, to transfer files to some device.
However, my mouse (Microsoft Arc Mouse) enters a connect-disconnect loop and can't be used.
See various logs provided, don't hesitate to ask for more.
Non-optimal solution :

Press the pairing button on the mouse. It changes its address (very annoying!), then bluetoothctl pair [new address is old one with one byte incremented]. This makes the mouse usable until the computer goes to sleep (screen off, programs and daemons still running), or until next reboot. Then the problem is back, I have to pair again with a new address again.

Tried
Solutions listed at bluetooth mouse disconnects , no one works for me, and I'm not sure it's exactly the same issue (the asker there has no loop).
I also tried trusting the mouse, not trusting it, enabling trust when it's on pairing mode (as seen at Bluetooth Mouse keeps connect/disconnect without move ), without any success.
Logs
On successful new pairing :
pair D5:75:2D:BC:81:60
Attempting to pair with D5:75:2D:BC:81:60
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:BC:81:60 Connected: yes
[Microsoft Arc Mouse]# [CHG] Device D5:75:2D:BC:81:60 Bonded: yes
[Microsoft Arc Mouse]# [CHG] Device D5:75:2D:BC:81:60 UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[Microsoft Arc Mouse]# [CHG] Device D5:75:2D:BC:81:60 UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[Microsoft Arc Mouse]# [CHG] Device D5:75:2D:BC:81:60 UUIDs: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[Microsoft Arc Mouse]# [CHG] Device D5:75:2D:BC:81:60 UUIDs: 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[Microsoft Arc Mouse]# [CHG] Device D5:75:2D:BC:81:60 UUIDs: 00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[Microsoft Arc Mouse]# [CHG] Device D5:75:2D:BC:81:60 ServicesResolved: yes
[Microsoft Arc Mouse]# [CHG] Device D5:75:2D:BC:81:60 Paired: yes
[Microsoft Arc Mouse]# [NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D5_75_2D_BC_81_60/service0008
        00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Generic Attribute Profile
[Microsoft Arc Mouse]# [NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D5_75_2D_BC_81_60/service0009
        0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Device Information
[Microsoft Arc Mouse]# [NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D5_75_2D_BC_81_60/service0009/char000a
        00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Manufacturer Name String
[Microsoft Arc Mouse]# [NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D5_75_2D_BC_81_60/service0009/char000c
        00002a50-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        PnP ID
[Microsoft Arc Mouse]# [NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D5_75_2D_BC_81_60/service000e
        0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Battery Service
[Microsoft Arc Mouse]# [NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D5_75_2D_BC_81_60/service000e/char000f
        00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Battery Level
[Microsoft Arc Mouse]# [NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
        /org/bluez/hci0/dev_D5_75_2D_BC_81_60/service000e/char000f/desc0011
        00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        Client Characteristic Configuration
[Microsoft Arc Mouse]# Pairing successful

Spammed to Syslog: (last line repeats many times)
bluetoothd[967]: profiles/input/hog-lib.c:info_read_cb() HID Information read failed: Request attribute has encountered an unlikely error
bluetoothd[967]: profiles/deviceinfo/deviceinfo.c:read_pnpid_cb() Error reading PNP_ID value: Request attribute has encountered an unlikely error
bluetoothd[967]: profiles/input/hog-lib.c:proto_mode_read_cb() Protocol Mode characteristic read failed: Request attribute has encountered an unlikely error
bluetoothd[967]: profiles/input/hog-lib.c:report_reference_cb() Read Report Reference descriptor failed: Request attribute has encountered an unlikely error

Disconnection loop seen from bluetoothctl: (never stops until I power off the mouse)
Agent registeredct to bluetoothd...[bluetooth]#         Microsoft Arc Mouse
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: no
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: no
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: no
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: no
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: no
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: no
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: no
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: no
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: no
[CHG] Device D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 Connected: yes

btmon (log is cut, it repeats infinitely)
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.71
btmon[4528]: = Note: Linux version 6.7.12-amd64 (x86_64)               0.487187
btmon[4528]: = Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                  0.487188
= New Index: 3C:F0:11:E4:1F:05 (Primary,USB,hci0)               [hci0] 0.487188
= Open Index: 3C:F0:11:E4:1F:05                                 [hci0] 0.487189
= Index Info: 3C:F0:11:E4:1F:05 (Intel Corp.)                   [hci0] 0.487189
bluetoothd[4165]: @ MGMT Open: b.. (privileged) version 1.22  {0x0001} 0.487190
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4               #1 [hci0] 1.339841
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 3585
        Reason: Connection Timeout (0x08)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8      {0x0001} [hci0] 1.339911
        LE Address: D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 (Static)
        Reason: Connection timeout (0x01)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan... (0x08|0x0041) plen 8  #2 [hci0] 1.382718
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Filter policy: Ignore not in accept list (0x01)
        PHYs: 0x01
        Entry 0: LE 1M
          Type: Passive (0x00)
          Interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
          Window: 30.000 msec (0x0030)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                  #3 [hci0] 1.383816
      LE Set Extended Scan Parameters (0x08|0x0041) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan... (0x08|0x0042) plen 6  #4 [hci0] 1.383942
        Extended scan: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
        Duration: 0 msec (0x0000)
        Period: 0.00 sec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                  #5 [hci0] 1.385856
      LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 26                    #6 [hci0] 1.390863
      LE Extended Advertising Report (0x0d)
        Num reports: 1
        Entry 0
          Event type: 0x0015
            Props: 0x0015
              Connectable
              Directed
              Use legacy advertising PDUs
            Data status: Complete
          Legacy PDU Type: ADV_DIRECT_IND (0x0015)
          Address type: Random (0x01)
          Address: D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 (Static)
          Primary PHY: LE 1M
          Secondary PHY: No packets
          SID: no ADI field (0xff)
          TX power: 127 dBm
          RSSI: -68 dBm (0xbc)
          Periodic advertising interval: 0.00 msec (0x0000)
          Direct address type: Public (0x00)
          Direct address: 3C:F0:11:E4:1F:05 (Intel Corporate)
          Data length: 0x00
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan... (0x08|0x0042) plen 6  #7 [hci0] 1.390950
        Extended scan: Disabled (0x00)
        Filter duplicates: Disabled (0x00)
        Duration: 0 msec (0x0000)
        Period: 0.00 sec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                  #8 [hci0] 1.393845
      LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Extended Create C.. (0x08|0x0043) plen 42  #9 [hci0] 1.393967
        Filter policy: Accept list is not used (0x00)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address type: Random (0x01)
        Peer address: D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 (Static)
        Initiating PHYs: 0x03
        Entry 0: LE 1M
          Scan interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
          Scan window: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
          Min connection interval: 7.50 msec (0x0006)
          Max connection interval: 7.50 msec (0x0006)
          Connection latency: 60 (0x003c)
          Supervision timeout: 3000 msec (0x012c)
          Min connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
          Max connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
        Entry 1: LE 2M
          Scan interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
          Scan window: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
          Min connection interval: 7.50 msec (0x0006)
          Max connection interval: 7.50 msec (0x0006)
          Connection latency: 60 (0x003c)
          Supervision timeout: 3000 msec (0x012c)
          Min connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
          Max connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                   #10 [hci0] 1.395843
      LE Extended Create Connection (0x08|0x0043) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 31                   #11 [hci0] 1.398862
      LE Enhanced Connection Complete (0x0a)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 3585
        Role: Central (0x00)
        Peer address type: Random (0x01)
        Peer address: D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 (Static)
        Local resolvable private address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (Non-Resolvable)
        Peer resolvable private address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (Non-Resolvable)
        Connection interval: 7.50 msec (0x0006)
        Connection latency: 60 (0x003c)
        Supervision timeout: 3000 msec (0x012c)
        Central clock accuracy: 0x00
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 13        {0x0001} [hci0] 1.398900
        LE Address: D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 (Static)
        Flags: 0x00000008
          Connection Locally Initiated
        Data length: 0
btmon[4528]: @ RAW Open: btmon (privileged) version 2.22      {0x0002} 1.398957
btmon[4528]: @ RAW Close: btmon                               {0x0002} 1.398961
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 4                    #12 [hci0] 1.399828
      LE Channel Selection Algorithm (0x14)
        Handle: 3585 Address: D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 (Static)
        Algorithm: #1 (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used... (0x08|0x0016) plen 2  #13 [hci0] 1.434680
        Handle: 3585 Address: D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 (Static)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                   #14 [hci0] 1.435824
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                   #15 [hci0] 1.436835
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 3585 Address: D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 (Static)
        Features: 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
          LE Encryption
< ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x00 dlen 11               #16 [hci0] 1.437037
      SMP: Pairing Request (0x01) len 6
        IO capability: KeyboardDisplay (0x04)
        OOB data: Authentication data not present (0x00)
        Authentication requirement: Bonding, MITM, SC, No Keypresses, CT2 (0x2d)
        Max encryption key size: 16
        Initiator key distribution: EncKey Sign LinkKey (0x0d)
        Responder key distribution: EncKey IdKey Sign LinkKey (0x0f)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5      #17 [hci0] 1.894869
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 3585 Address: D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 (Static)
        Count: 1
        #16: len 11 (0 Kb/s)
        Latency: 457 msec (457-457 msec ~457 msec)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 3585 flags 0x02 dlen 11               #18 [hci0] 1.906686
      SMP: Pairing Response (0x02) len 6
        IO capability: NoInputNoOutput (0x03)
        OOB data: Authentication data not present (0x00)
        Authentication requirement: Bonding, No MITM, Legacy, No Keypresses (0x01)
        Max encryption key size: 16
        Initiator key distribution: <none> (0x00)
        Responder key distribution: EncKey (0x01)
@ MGMT Event: User Confirmation Re.. (0x000f) plen 12  {0x0001} [hci0] 1.906760
        LE Address: D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 (Static)
        Confirm hint: 0x01
        Value: 0x00000000
bluetoothd[4165]: @ MGMT Command: U.. (0x001d) plen 7  {0x0001} [hci0] 1.906920
        LE Address: D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 (Static)
@ MGMT Event: Authentication Failed (0x0011) plen 8    {0x0001} [hci0] 1.906940
        LE Address: D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 (Static)
        Status: Authentication Failed (0x05)
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 10        {0x0001} [hci0] 1.906950
      User Confirmation Negative Reply (0x001d) plen 7
        Status: Success (0x00)
        LE Address: D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 (Static)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x00 dlen 6                #19 [hci0] 1.906996
      SMP: Pairing Failed (0x05) len 1
        Reason: Passkey entry failed (0x01)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5      #20 [hci0] 1.909868
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 3585 Address: D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 (Static)
        Count: 1
        #19: len 6 (24 Kb/s)
        Latency: 2 msec (2-457 msec ~230 msec)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4              #21 [hci0] 4.992038
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 3585 Address: D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 (Static)
        Reason: Connection Timeout (0x08)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8      {0x0001} [hci0] 4.992106
        LE Address: D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 (Static)
        Reason: Connection timeout (0x01)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan.. (0x08|0x0041) plen 8  #22 [hci0] 5.042720
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Filter policy: Ignore not in accept list (0x01)
        PHYs: 0x01
        Entry 0: LE 1M
          Type: Passive (0x00)
          Interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
          Window: 30.000 msec (0x0030)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                 #23 [hci0] 5.043010
      LE Set Extended Scan Parameters (0x08|0x0041) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan.. (0x08|0x0042) plen 6  #24 [hci0] 5.043119
        Extended scan: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
        Duration: 0 msec (0x0000)
        Period: 0.00 sec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                 #25 [hci0] 5.045055
      LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 26                   #26 [hci0] 5.047069
      LE Extended Advertising Report (0x0d)
        Num reports: 1
        Entry 0
          Event type: 0x0015
            Props: 0x0015
              Connectable
              Directed
              Use legacy advertising PDUs
            Data status: Complete
          Legacy PDU Type: ADV_DIRECT_IND (0x0015)
          Address type: Random (0x01)
          Address: D5:75:2D:B6:81:60 (Static)
          Primary PHY: LE 1M
          Secondary PHY: No packets
          SID: no ADI field (0xff)
          TX power: 127 dBm
          RSSI: -71 dBm (0xb9)
          Periodic advertising interval: 0.00 msec (0x0000)
          Direct address type: Public (0x00)
          Direct address: 3C:F0:11:E4:1F:05 (Intel Corporate)
          Data length: 0x00
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan.. (0x08|0x0042) plen 6  #27 [hci0] 5.047152
        Extended scan: Disabled (0x00)
        Filter duplicates: Disabled (0x00)
        Duration: 0 msec (0x0000)
        Period: 0.00 sec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                 #28 [hci0] 5.050051
      LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)


Configuration:
/etc/bluetooth/input.conf has:
IdleTimeout=0
UserspaceHID=true

I tried with true and false for UserspaceHID, same behavior.
